# sg_split - why clearing offset?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, dma

In Linux kernel library, i.e. [lib/sg_split.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/sg_split.c#L77) in the following function...

```
static void sg_split_phys(struct sg_splitter *splitters, const int nb_splits)
{
    int i, j;
    struct scatterlist *in_sg, *out_sg;
    struct sg_splitter *split;

    for (i = 0, split = splitters; i < nb_splits; i++, split++) {
        in_sg = split->in_sg0;
        out_sg = split->out_sg;
        for (j = 0; j < split->nents; j++, out_sg++) {
            *out_sg = *in_sg;
            if (!j) {
                out_sg->offset += split->skip_sg0;
                out_sg->length -= split->skip_sg0;
            } else {
                out_sg->offset = 0;
            }
            sg_dma_address(out_sg) = 0;
            sg_dma_len(out_sg) = 0;
            in_sg = sg_next(in_sg);
        }
        out_sg[-1].length = split->length_last_sg;
        sg_mark_end(out_sg - 1);
    }
}
```

Why do we clear the offset of `out_sg` when not in the first iteration of the interior loop? By doing so we no longer are able to get the virtual address of that particular region of memory.

Comment: You have one contiguous buffer, let's say page=0x1200, offset=0x154, length=0x54000. The segment size requirement, for example, 0x1000 (one page of 4K), so, it will produce SG list out of plenty elements, where only first has an offset and the last one will have length < 0x1000. Maybe you didn't get what **split** means in this case?

Comment: You have one continuous buffer in each node in the scatterlist but the scatterlist as a whole does not necessarily (and usually does not) describe a contiguous area in virtual memory, indeed the inception of the scatterlist was due to the desire to in a single call DMA areas in virtual memory that are not contiguous and also not on the same page. Again what I'm saying is because nodes in a scatterlist do not necessarily (and again usually do not) describe virtually contiguous regions, then without the offset there is no way to determine where in the page the memory is.